# Json giving 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, laravel-4

on Firefox, only on firefox it will popup and give you a warning "This web page is being redirected to a new location. Would you like to resend the for form you have typed to the new location."

I got no form , i use javascript to extract values from textbox

I checked on firebug it says 
PUT /admin/submit-scan/ 301 moved permanently
PUT submit-scan 302 Found

My JS

```
function submitGoods(){
    var registeredNo = $('input[name=registeredno]').val();
    var weight = $('input[name=weight]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/admin/submit-scan/',
            data: {
                registeredNo: registeredNo,
                weight: weight,
                _token: csrfToken
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data){

                data = $.parseJSON(data);
            });

}
```

My Route

```
Route::put('submit-scan', 'Controllers\Admin\DashboardController@putUpdateSubmitScan');
```

My controller

```
 public function putUpdateSubmitScan()
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::json(array('success' => 1, 'data' => "test"));
        }
    }
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Removing the trailing slash should do the trick (most probably prior to Laravel 4.1, see below).

```
url: '/admin/submit-scan'
```

**Update**

As mentioned in [Laravel4 POST unexplained redirect to GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268863/laravel4-post-unexplained-redirect-to-get)

Laravel `bootstrap/start.php` is calling `$app->redirectIfTrailingSlash();` which seems to be the culprit. This has been changed in Laravel 4.1:

http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1

Comment: laravel 4.2.11 here, using angular the tralling slash problem persist.

Comment: laravel 4.2 here, same issue :(

Comment: I've fixed this by changing my redirect rules in the .htaccess to 307 instead of 301 (laravel default)

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I lost an hour but thanks to you, I lost no more!!

Comment: Wauw .. I've been running around this problem my whole day .. and this fix on .htaccess solved it!!!

Comment: Thank you so much it was doing my head on