# jQuery AJAX Laravel 5 return type is different in different environments

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Here's my ajax POST request:

```
        $('input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var token = $(this).parents('form').find('input[name=_token]').val();
            var data = $(this).parents('form').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'formData': data,
                        '_token': token,
                    },
                    url: '/myurl/items/',
                    context: document.getElementById('content'),
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        console.log(typeof(data));
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
        });
```

Here's my controller:

```
        if(Request::ajax())
        {
            $inputForm = Request::get('formData');
            parse_str($inputForm, $inputData);
            if(Item::create($inputData)) {
                $new_item = Item::where('name', $inputData['name'])->get()[0];
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'id' => $new_item->id
                ]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
```

Here's the output of `typeof(data)` and `console.log(data)` on my local machine:

> object
>
> Object {success: true, id: "5"}

and here's the output on my AWS EC2 instance:

> string

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
>     ...  </head>
> 
> </html>
```

I've been debugging for hours and it doesn't make any sense at all. Can somebody tell me what's going on in here?

Comment: what's in the rest of the html string? likely an important error page message. Inspect response in network tab of browser dev tools

Comment: The html string is the HTML of the page that I am sending the AJAX request from. It's kinda long, so I didn't want to copy it over. I checked the network tab, and there was nothing

Comment: can't possibly be `nothing`...where did the string come from...the request. Sounds like a path problem perhaps

Comment: sorry I didn't refresh the page. Okay I see a difference, on my EC2 instance I got  `POST 301 Moved Permanently`, whereas in my local machine is `POST 200 OK`. I wonder what that means?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934588/json-giving-301-moved-permanently

Just removed the trailing slash in the AJAX Post url